# Исключение элемента из выборки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как селектором :not или методом not() исключить из обернутого набора вложенный элемент? Есть такая структура:

```
<a class="link">
  <div>
    <img></img>
  </div>
  <i></i>
</a>
```

Как с jQuery выбрать .link, при этом, чтобы дальнейшие манипуляции с ним не затронули вложенный i? Грубо говоря, чтобы когда по клику на иконке не срабатывал тот же обработчик, что висит на .link. Я как-то так пробую, но не выходит:

```
$('.link:not(i)').click(function(e) {
}
```

Comment: надо именно через not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так. C помощью `e.target` и `.is` узнаём, на что кликнули, и если это `i`, то ничего не делаем (`return false;`).

```js
$(".link").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('i')) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log("click!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
  <div>click</div>
  <i>не click</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично. А может знаете каким образом сделать, чтобы элементы, которые удаляются при клика на них, после перезагрузки не появлялись заново?

Comment: @BlackFire Это уже смотря откуда эти элементы там *"берутся"*. Например, при клике, помимо *удаления* из `DOM` также отправить запрос на сервер, который *"скажет"* серверу больше этот элемент не выводить. Тут вариантов масса. Оформите отдельным вопросом с подробным описанием "что и откуда" надо удалять.